# Blank table names when trying to link ODBC tables in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, odbc

I am trying to create a linked table via External Data -> New Data Source -> From Other Sources -> ODBC Database in Microsoft Access. I am able to successfully connect, but when the Link Table window pops up, all of the table names are blank [(Blank table name)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQTZ0.png). If I try to click on one of the blank tables, an error message pops up saying "Invalid Argument".

I have been able to query the Datasource using the Query Designer, and I am able to see the tables in Excel when using the Data -> Get Data -> From Other Sources -> From ODBC. I have also been able to add some print statements to the ODBC code and I am seeing in the raw output from the SQLFetch function that the table name is present.

If anyone has any idea as to what may be happening, or even a way to somehow to debug the Microsoft Access calls that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: And your ODBC source and driver is ... ?

Comment: The driver is from Dr. DeeBee (http://www.syware.com/prodlib/odbc), but we build the driver ourselves and can modify the source code as needed.

Comment: I can't see how we should be able to debug your in-house code.

Comment: Yes I understand that would be difficult, I was more asking if people had encountered the issue where the tables are blank in access, since everything else seems to be working correctly.

Comment: I see. But no, I've never seen or heard about this.